# Switching Between Front and Back Camera Previews After Fixed Time

Tags: android

So I am showing front and back camera preview inside a view and I want to switch the previews (from front to back and then again front after every 2 seconds) and whatever I may try, I am failing. Here is the code where I try to switch the views (*is it even the right place to make the switch between the cameras?*):

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        // infinite for loop - doesn't work
        if(camIter == 1){
            cleanup();
            initCamera(getContext());
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            camIter = 2;
            // Thread.sleep(2000); - Doesn't work!
        }
        if(camIter == 2){
            cleanup();
            initCamera(getContext());
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            camIter = 1;
            // Thread.sleep(2000); - Doesn't work!
        }                

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CameraExample: " + "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is the full class in which I am trying to do it (using switch to change camera previews):

```
public class CameraExample extends AnimatedViewContainer {

    private final static String TAG = "CameraExample";

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview frontPreview, backPreview;
    private Context mContext;
    public int camIter = 1;

    public CameraExample(Context context, int i) {
        super(context, i);

        frontPreview = null;
        backPreview = null;
        mContext = context;

        initCamera(context);
    }

    private void initCamera(Context context) {

        // Check if this device has a camera
        if (!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

            // No camera on this device
            Log.d("Camera", "CameraExample: " + "this device has no camera");
        } else {

            // This device has a camera
            int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            if (numCameras >= 1) {

                switch (camIter) {
                    case 1:
                        for (int cameraId = 1; cameraId < numCameras; cameraId++) {

                            mCamera = getCameraInstance(cameraId);
                            if (mCamera != null) {
                                CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
                                Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);
                                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                                    try {

                                        //Create our Preview view and set it as the content of this LinearLayout View
                                        frontPreview = new CameraPreview(context, mCamera, cameraId);
                                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                                if (createView() == false) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for (int cameraId = 0; cameraId < 1; cameraId++) {
                            mCamera = getCameraInstance(cameraId);
                            if (mCamera != null) {
                                CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
                                Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);
                                if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                                    try {

                                        //Create our Preview view and set it as the content of this LinearLayout View
                                        backPreview = new CameraPreview(context, mCamera, cameraId);
                                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                                if (createView() == false) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(int cameraId) {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            // attempt to get a Camera instance
            c = Camera.open(cameraId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            Log.d(TAG, "CameraExample: " + "camera not available (in use or does not exist); " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // returns null if camera is unavailable
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateViewContent(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup parentGroup, View[] containerViews, int index) {
        containerViews[index] = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example_camera, parentGroup, false);
        FrameLayout previewFrame = (FrameLayout) containerViews[index].findViewById(R.id.preview);


            // set camera preview
            if (camIter == 1) {
                previewFrame.addView(frontPreview);
            }
            if (camIter == 2) {
                previewFrame.addView(backPreview);
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    // A basic Camera preview class
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

        private Context mContext;
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private int mCameraId;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera, int cameraId) {
            super(context);
            mContext = context;
            mCamera = camera;
            mCameraId = cameraId;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {

                // infinite for loop - doesn't work
                if(camIter == 1){
                    cleanup();
                    initCamera(getContext());
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    camIter = 2;
                    // Thread.sleep(2000); - Doesn't work!
                }
                if(camIter == 2){
                    cleanup();
                    initCamera(getContext());
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    camIter = 1;
                    // Thread.sleep(2000); - Doesn't work!
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CameraExample: " + "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: Remove mCamera.stopPreview() from cleanup().

Comment: For every 2 second you can use CountDownTimer it is easy and fast solution

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Can you show a sample! This has been bugging me for ages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay =2000; //milliseconds

//action will perform every two seconds 
h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        switchCamera();
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);

private void switchCamera() {
        cleanup();
        initCamera(getContext());
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        camIter = camIter == 1 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

Comment: `Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called` error